# What 5e spells summon outsiders besides celestials, fey, and elementals?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I can't find *Summon Monster.* Are there any other spells that can summon Outsiders other than Celestials, Fey, and Elementals or is that it?

Is it maybe a conjuration school wizard thing? (I did google.)

Comment: It's worth noting that 5e doesn't have "outsiders" per se. The creatures that were previously classified as outsiders have all been reclassified as other creature types, mostly fiends, celestials, fey, elementals, and aberrations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Outside of *Conjure Animals*, *Conjure Celestial*, *Conjure Elemental*, *Conjure Fey*, *Conjure Minor Elementals*, and *Conjure Woodland Beings*, there are a few more summoning spells, although I suspect none are what you're looking for.

The *Find Familiar* and *Find Steed* spells summon extremely specific creatures that are basically Wizard and Paladin class features respectively.

*Planar Ally* is a Cleric spell that summons a celestial, elemental, or fiend of the deity's choice. But you don't get to control it, so the results of this spell are pretty much entirely up to the DM.

*Gate* can summon any extraplanar creature that you can name, but you likewise don't get to control it, and, of course, it's a 9th-level spell.

You might be interested in the [Unearthed Arcana article](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/old-black-magic) which came out **today** (nice timing for this question), and offers a variety of demon-summoning spells.

In summary: There is no equivalent to the *Summon Monster* spells of previous editions.

Comment: anyone who summons creatures even every once in a while really should be aware of this [document from WOTC](https://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/MM_MonstersCR.pdf) . 

Get it, print it, your DM will thank you for not wasting half an hour figuring out what you can summon with which spell.